# Basic misunderstanding of LINQ to SQL and foreign keys

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working on a much larger project, and can't seem to get LINQ to SQL working the way I expect it to. I created a simple subset of the project so I can use LinqPad to try to make sure I have a basic understanding of how this should work.

Clearly, I don't: I've created two very simple tables - `customer` and `job`. The `customer` table has an `ID` (auto-increment) and a `Name`, the `Job` table has an `ID` (ai), a `Name`, and a `CustomerID` (foreign key to ID in the `customer` table).

When I run the following code against an initially empty database:

```
void Main()
{
    string custName = "James";
    string[] jobNames = new string[] {"Home Depot", "Menards", "Sam's Club" };

    var cust = customer.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == custName);

    if (cust == null)
    {
        cust = new customer
        {
            Name = custName
        };
        customer.InsertOnSubmit(cust);
    }

    foreach(var jn in jobNames)
    {
        if (!job.Any(j => j.Customer.Name == cust.Name && j.Name == jn))
            job.InsertOnSubmit(new job {
                Name = jn,
                Customer = cust
            });
    }

    SubmitChanges();
    
    customer.Dump();
    job.Dump();
}
```

I would expect to end up with 1 customer and 3 jobs in the database - that's all good. But the generated SQL and the setting of the customer IDs are not at all what I expect:

SQL --

```
SELECT t0.ID, t0.Name
FROM customer AS t0
WHERE (t0.Name = @p0)
LIMIT 0, 1
-- p0 = [James]

SELECT COUNT(*) AS value
FROM job AS t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer AS t1
  ON (t1.ID = t0.CustomerID)
WHERE ((t1.Name = @p0) AND (t0.Name = @p1))
-- p0 = [James]
-- p1 = [Home Depot]

SELECT COUNT(*) AS value
FROM job AS t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer AS t1
  ON (t1.ID = t0.CustomerID)
WHERE ((t1.Name = @p0) AND (t0.Name = @p1))
-- p0 = [James]
-- p1 = [Menards]

SELECT COUNT(*) AS value
FROM job AS t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer AS t1
  ON (t1.ID = t0.CustomerID)
WHERE ((t1.Name = @p0) AND (t0.Name = @p1))
-- p0 = [James]
-- p1 = [Sam's Club]

INSERT INTO job(CustomerID, ID, Name)
VALUES (NULL, 0, @p0)
-- p0 = [Home Depot]

INSERT INTO job(CustomerID, ID, Name)
VALUES (NULL, 0, @p0)
-- p0 = [Menards]

INSERT INTO job(CustomerID, ID, Name)
VALUES (NULL, 0, @p0)
-- p0 = [Sam's Club]

INSERT INTO customer(ID, Name)
VALUES (0, @p0)
-- p0 = [James]

SELECT t0.ID, t0.Name
FROM customer AS t0

SELECT t0.CustomerID, t0.ID, t0.Name
FROM job AS t0
```

Results in LinqPad:

[image: LinqPad output]

I thought that the beauty of LINQ to SQL was that I don't have to manage to set the foreign keys and that I should be able to do what I'm trying to do here with a single hit to the database. What am I missing?

**EDIT:** So I guess I understand the customer IDs being set to NULL because the generated SQL is calling INSERT on the jobs before the INSERT on the customer, hence there is no ID yet. Why would it do that? Also, if I run the same query again, I get three more rows in the jobs table, but the CustomerIDs are all still set to NULL.

Comment: Step 1 - think about how to write the SQL (hint - it will involve `IN`).

Comment: @mjwills if I were to write the SQL for this simple example, I'm not sure where I would use `IN`, unless you are referring to a method to simplify my foreach loop, which is hardly the point of the question.

Comment: Is this using LinqPad's auto-generated data context or your own? It would appear that Linq2Sql **thinks** that the Customer table depends on Job table (and I suspect customer.job is a single Job rather than EntitySet<Job>) and hence that the jobs need to be saved before the customer ?

Answer (score 1):

Linq query have no issues.
check DB table relations

[image]

[image]

Comment: I recreated my test platform in SQL Server (as you had clearly done) and you're right, the code works exactly as I had expected. Does anyone have any ideas why MySQL (actually MariaDB) would behave differently?

Comment: the problem is in reference. please check how foreign key got created in db. (sorry dont have much experience on mysql) https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/mysql-foreign-key-constraint/